# Rewrite rules for image sharing

Tags: image, file, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I am making an image storage for screencloud, doing so i'd like to have theses urls working:
Any urls that ends with a file extension redirects as normal:

http://serv/           -> /index.php
http://serv/index.php -> /index.php

Any urls that do not have extension or is png as returns the file:

http: // serv/scr1801172229     -> /scr/scr1801172229.png
http: // serv/scr1801172229.png -> /scr/scr1801172229.png

I tried to learn how to use rewrite from nginx though I can't find any good tutorial. And every thing I tried did not work, including this which is the closest thing I got:

```
rewrite /index /index.php break;
rewrite /(.*)$ /scr/$1.png break;
rewrite /(.*)$.png /scr/$1.png break;
```

The last line does nothing (It goes 404)
The first line works to get the index displayed though resources are not loaded, anything else than index won't work and I can't get my .php in the url as usual.
The middle line actually works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand all of your requirements, but it seems that some of your URIs map to files in the document root, and some map to files in a subdirectory called `scr`.

Rather than using `rewrite ... break` you may be able to test the various locations and file extensions by using a `try_files` directive. For example:

```
root /path/to/root;

location / {
    try_files $uri /scr$uri /src$uri.png /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Wow I would have never thought of this, and it actually works like a charm, exactly what I needed! Thanks